# DateTimePicker converting date to m, d, yyy

Tags: c#, date, visual-studio-2012, datetimepicker

I have a DateTimePicker called dtpRental and i need to display the date as 9/27/2014 in a list box.
Need to show like this
 lstInvoice.Items.Add("Rental date                         (9/27/2014)");
But show the current date

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
string str = today.Month + "\\" + today.Day + "\\" + today.Year;

lstInvoice.Items.Add("Rental date (" + str + ")");
```